# Delphi 7 - Adding watch to variable which is referenced using 'with' command

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'm working on a large software project which makes use of the 'with' command and I am having difficulty with debugging.

Take the following code as an example:

```
with record do
begin
 record_property = 'some value'; 
end;
```

If I am debugging this code and I want to see the value of record_property I have to add a watch on record.record_property, even if I am paused within the 'with' block. Is there a setting or add-on for Delphi 7 which allows the scope created by a 'with' block to carry over into the watch window?

This would make my life a lot easier as there are many cases of nested 'with' blocks which make it difficult to figure out how to add watches.

Comment: And that's one of the reasons you shouldn't use with statements. It's hard to debug and produces unclear code. Unfortunately there is no workaround for your problem, afaik. If the debugger can't figure out what you want to watch, how can a plugin or expert do it?

Comment: Preaching to the choir mate but unfortunately I have a couple hundred thousands of lines of legacy code written this way to maintain. Thanks for letting me know that there isn't really any solution though, though I may have been able to make life a bit easier!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The record pointer used in the `with`statement is *(most likely)* loaded into the `eax` register.

With your breakpoint hit at the `record_property = 'some value'` line, you can get the record instance by

- opening the assembly window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>)
- step once to load the pointer into `eax`
- evaluate the expression `TMyRecordType(pointer(eax)^)`

or one step less *(as per screenshot)*

- opening the assembly window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>)
- evaluate the expression `TMyRecordType(pointer(integer(ebp)-4)^)`

*Replace TMyRecordType with the actual type of your record*

---

Above would be my first quick attempt to get the values you are interested in.

If that doesn't work, I don't see any other option other than opening the CPU window and look for yourself into what register the record pointer gets loaded.

[image]

---

**Edit**

To add a watch to your record variable, you can't depend on the volatile `eax` register. You would have to get the contents of `eax` and use that in your watch.

- Get the content of `eax` by using `Pointer(eax)` in the evaluate window
- Use that address in a watch expression: ex. `TMyRecordType(pointer($4A3DB8)^)`

Comment: I'm going to mark this as answered as this works and it's useful to know. However, I doubt that I will get much use out of this as you need to be on the line straight after the 'with' command to get the correct value for eax. Cheers Lieven.

Comment: Even if the window of opportunity is narrow, that's really impressive!

Comment: @afrazier - thx but the window of opportunity really isn't that small at all. For each line or assignment to a record property, somehow the record pointer needs to get loaded into a register. Looking at the assembly window for my testcase, this always seems to be `eax` *(but I wouldn't rely on this to always be true)*

Comment: @Starky - *as you need to be on the line straight after the 'with' command to get the correct value for eax* - No you don't <g> but it does require you to look at the assembly window to get the right address.

Comment: Interesting to know. The issue with `with` is that there is a pointer to the record, you just don't know what the address is. You might as well create your own pointer to the record and be able to access it in the debugger.

Comment: @MarcusAdams - True but that requires a code change. OP would do well then by entirely removing the `with` clause. He wouldn't need to use the assembly window or add a pointer.

Comment: @Starky - Your comment about the limitted use of this "technique" has kept me awake all week. *(not entirely true but it could have <g>)* Did you actually run into a case where you couldn't retrieve the right pointer from the assembly window? I would love to have a shot at that.